# Telegram VoIP key exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, voip

We've been trying to understand how Telegram's VoIP end-to-end encryption works.

### Key Exchange

Detailed description of the key exchange algorithm is documented on the [Telegram website](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end/voice-calls#key-generation).

Here is the crux of the algorithm, taken from the [same page](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end/voice-calls#key-verification):

1. A->B: generates *a* and sends *g_a_hash* := $hash(g^a)$
2. B->A: stores *g_a_hash*, generates *b* and sends *g_b* := $g^b$
3. A->B: computes key $(g^b)^a$, then sends g_a := $g^a$ and the fingerprint $f\left((g^b)^a\right)$.
4. B: checks $hash(g^a)$ = *g_a_hash*, computes key $(g^a)^b$ and checks $f\left((g^a)^b\right) = f\left((g^b)^a\right)$.

For the $hash(x)$ function, they use SHA256.
Fingerprint $f(x)$ is the lower 64 bits from SHA1.
All messages between $A$ to $B$ go through Telegram server that basically re-transmits messages to the other party.

### Questions

1. Why are they using $hash(g^a)$ in the first step? They say that sending the $hash(g^a)$ first doesn't allow the party $B$ to select $b$ such that $hash((g^a)^b)$ will have some specific properties. Do such attacks exist?
2. Why $f\left((g^b)^a\right)$ is sent in the last step? They explain it "as an implementation sanity check". Does it make sense?

Comment: I don't see the step you describe in your second question in your protocol summary?

Comment: @SEJPM Thank you for spotting this! I've copied the protocol outline verbatim from the Telegram page, and yes, it doesn't show the full picture as required for our questions. The outline and the second question have been clarified.

Comment: ‘Make sense’ and Telegram crypto do not belong in the same sentence unless there's an odd number of negatives involved…